# jQuery change href when image slider changes

Tags: jquery, arrays, slider, href

I have a working image slider that uses jQuery to change the image (yes, I know using background images in DIVs is not the best practice, but it's the only method that works with the rest of my page):

My HTML:

```
<a id="featuredLink" href="#"><div class="featuredImages" style="background-image:url('http://www.placehold.it/2000x500/00ff00.png')"><div class="slide"></div></div></a>
```

jQuery:

```
var urls = [ 'http://www.google.com','http://www.microsoft.com','http://www.yahoo.com' ];
var images = [ 'http://www.placehold.it/2000x500/ff0000.png','http://www.placehold.it/2000x500/00ff00.png','http://www.placehold.it/2000x500/0000ff.png' ];
var cur_image = 0;
function changeBackground() {
    cur_image++;
    if ( cur_image >= images.length )
        cur_image = 0;

    // change images
    $( '.featuredImages' ).css({
        backgroundImage: 'url(' + images[ cur_image ] + ')'
    });
    $( '.featuredImages .slide' ).fadeOut( 3000, function(){
        $( this ).css({
            backgroundImage: 'url(' + images[ cur_image ] + ')'
        }).show();
    } );

}


setInterval( changeBackground, 10000 );
```

And CSS:

```
.featuredImages {
    position:absolute;
    margin: 0; 
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    background: transparent url('') no-repeat center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.featuredImages .slide { 
    position: absolute; 
    margin: 0; 
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    background: transparent url('') no-repeat center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hnS9U/1/

I would like to change the href of that anchor tag ("featuredLinks") when the image swaps so that it links to the page that the images relates to.

I would like to use an array to store the links ("urls") and the same loop counter that is used for the images to keep track of what link to use.

Any pointers in the right direction would be great!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, `href`s are no more than attributes of the `a` element. All you need to do is change the value of that attribute. As for the array, if you are planning to use two arrays and you are planning to have the indexes of each correspond to their counterparts in the other array, then you can use the same indexer, `cur_image`, for the `href`s, as well.

Have you tried:

```
$("#featuredLink").attr("href", "hrefOfNewImage");
```

In your case, this would be more like:

```
$("#featuredLink").attr("href", urls[cur_image]);
```

In your function, this would look like:

```
function changeBackground() {
    cur_image++;
    if ( cur_image >= images.length )
        cur_image = 0;

    // change link
    $("#featuredLink").attr("href", urls[cur_image]);

    // change images
    $( '.featuredImages' ).css({
        backgroundImage: 'url(' + images[ cur_image ] + ')'
    });
    $( '.featuredImages .slide' ).fadeOut( 3000, function(){
        $( this ).css({
            backgroundImage: 'url(' + images[ cur_image ] + ')'
        }).show();
    } );

};
```

Let me know if you have any more questions. Good luck! :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but I'm pretty new to JS. Would you mind showing me how to add this to the code I provided? Thank you!

Comment: Done! If the rest of your code is working then that should work right away.

Comment: Thank you very much! That works great! If the cursor is already on the image the href does not change until the cursor is taken off the image and placed back on. Is that a cause of the browser or something that can be corrected with jQuery? Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hnS9U/2/

Comment: The URL should change, but the little popup that reads you the URL might not That's a browser thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code in changeBackground():

```
$('#featuredLink').attr("href", urls[cur_image]);
```

I used cur_image but you can create another var!

Your HTML semantical is bad bad bad... A div inside a link isn't semantical, try change to span.